# How to Place “-1-“ on the first page in the upper right corner 0.5 inch from the right edge of the paper

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, margins

I am formatting my thesis and I required to place this:
-1- 
on the right corner of the first page of the first chapter only.

I tried something like:

```
\null\hfill\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
   \text{-1-} \\
 \end{tabular}
```

Also I tried

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \rhead{-1-}
```

non of them seem to work. Do you have any suggestions, I appreciated.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: The top right corner of a page is a pretty unusual place for a page number; that said, I suggest you define a custom page style with hte help of the `fancyhdr` package and then use a `\thispagestyle` declaration to use that particular page style only on the first page of the first chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curiously, I’ve not been able to find a question that qualifies as an exact duplicate of this one (but I could be wrong).  Well, try to see if the following sample code does what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % unrelated to the problem, but recommended in general
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{Gnus of the World}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[OR]{--\thepage--}%
    \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The first chapter}
\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\chapter{The second chapter}
Fringilla eius adipisci.

\chapter{The third chapter}
Nonnulla enim.

\end{document}
```

## Edit

Wait a minute: I overlooked your request for the horizontal placement of the page number!  Here’s an amended MWE that takes care of this too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % unrelated to the problem, but recommended in general
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{Gnus of the World}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[OR]{%
        \makebox[0pt][l]{%
            \makebox
                [\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in\relax]%
                [r]{--\thepage--\hspace{.5in}}%
        }%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The first chapter}
\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\chapter{The second chapter}
Fringilla eius adipisci.

\chapter{The third chapter}
Nonnulla enim.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown by GuM you can use `fancyhdr` for this or the facilities provided by the `memoir` class. Here is another way using a zero-sized `picture` to locate the "-1".

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\incorner}{\begin{picture}(0,0)%  zero-sized picture takes no space
  \put(450,150){\normalfont\normalsize -1-}% place the -1- with regular font
\end{picture}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[First]{\incorner First}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

In the macro `\incorner` the numbers `450,150` are the x and y locations of the -1- text with respect to where the macro is used (in the MWE wrt to the start of the chapter title). The two `\normal...` are to ensure that the normal font in the normal size is used. The `\incorner` macro is called just before the chapter title text but as it should not appear in the ToC use the optional argument to put just the text into the ToC.

As you haven't said what class you are using, what paper, what layout on the paper, etc., you will have to adjust the `450,150` values to position the "-1-" to suit the thesis nitpickers. (You will have to do something similar with `fancyhdr` or `memoir`.)

In general a zero-sized `picture` can be very useful for manually positioning items on a page.